# Form not submitting information (Django)

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create comments for a django blog project, but the form submission button does not doing anything when clicked.

Here is the html for the template.

```
<form role="form" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <p>Comment: </p>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the view I'm trying to call when I press the button.

```
def detail(request, slug):
    context ={}
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    # print(request.method)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    if form.is_valid():
        t = form.save(commit=False)
        t.commentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        t.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogpost_detail'))
    comment_list=Comments.objects.order_by('-commentTime')[:25]
    context = {'comment':comment_list,'form':form, 'post': post}
    return render(request, 'blog/blogpost_detail.html', context)
```

And here is the form that is called in the template.

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Comments
      fields=('commentText', 'commentImage',)
      exclude =('post','commentTime',)
      widgets={
           'commentText': forms.Textarea(attrs={'col':10}),
       }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: your `form.is_valid` should be inside the `POST` check. By not doing that `form.is_valid` evaluates everytime (even for GET), which is not what you intend to do. Also, make sure the current URL is where you intend to `POST` to. Or you would have to explicitly specify the `action`

Comment: your `form` tag has no `action`; `<form action="/url/to/post/to" ...>`

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys! @karthikr I'm on the url I want to POST on but it's still not doing anything when clicked.

Comment: What happens when you press the button as-is - does the page reload? For debugging, I would put an `else` block on the `if form.is_valid()` block - with the system set up as it is now, there's no visible difference between a POST that doesn't pass the form and a GET. The form might be submitting each time, but silently failing because the form data isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `action` attribute in the form tag. Since you're posting to the same URL, it should be

```
<form action="." method="post " role°"form">
```